# После удаление чекбокса страница возвращалась на этап вывода таблицы с чекбоксами

Tags: php

Есть у меня селект где выводит некоторую информацию за период по датам для выбранного id.

После вывода таблицы, к каждой строке присваивается чекбокс, после выделения нужные записей по чекбоксу, можно удалить запись.

Когда удаляет записи, я делаю возврат страницы на выбранный id таким образом.

```
$rnd = get_rnd();
echo '<a href="stack_over.php?id='.$id.'&amp;rnd='.$rnd.'">вернуться</a>';
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли реализовать возврат страницы где открывалась таблица с моим селектом для выбранного id?

Comment: Вернутся на страницу с которой был переход `header("location: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);`

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ.
Есть какой нибудь небольшой пример как это делается?
Т.к. в php пока очень слаб.

Comment: Уберите в файле весь вывод типа `echo` , `print_r` и после выполнения нужных операций просто вставьте строчку `header("location: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);`

Comment: Я не могу показать пример без кода(ваших попыток), я не знаю что у вас там есть и как вам помочь. Покажите что вы пытались сделать

Comment: Спасибо большое, действительно, добавил header("location: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
Вернуло на страницу с таблицей!